# Debian and CentOS PAM rules matching

Tags: debian, centos, pam

I need to configure PAM rules on Debian system to use LDAP authentification. Earlier I did it on CentOS and I'm not sure that I understand PAM rules matching on their systems right.

On CentOS I've edited these files in /etc/pam.d/:

```
fingerprint-auth
password-auth
smartcard-auth
system-auth
```

*it's soft links to {filename}-ac files*

In Debian I see only one of them:

```
system-auth
```

But here are a few files like **common-{auth,password,session}** and as I think **system-auth** consists of them (am I right?).

So what PAM-files I need to edit in Debian?

I found another way (right way, as I dare to say): **auth-client-config**, a script on Python from Ubuntu that change PAM-rules in files /etc/pam.d/common-{filename}, but is that enough? Do I need to edit system-auth manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/etc/pam.d/system-auth` is not part of Debian, you must have created it yourself. If all other files under `/etc/pam.d` are pristine, then enabling LDAP via `dpkg-reconfigure libpam-runtime` should add the lines necessary for basic functionality to `common-*` (which are included by the various service config files: `login`, `sshd`, and so on). Of course, all of the above depends on *libpam-ldapd* (and consequently: *nslcd*) being installed and configured correctly (which automatically enables itself in *libpam-runtime*, so `dpkg-reconfigure` shouldn't be needed unless you disabled it beforehand). Most probably you'll also need *libnss-ldapd* to provide the user database.